# How do I get the value of the input text when using a class, not a function approach to CodeMirror?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, class, codemirror

I am writing a leetcode clone using reactjs and nodejs. To challenge myself I am writing it as a class and not with an overall function. In either event, I can't seem to figure out how to get <button onClick={() => axios.post("http://localhost:80/python", {code})}>[Run] to return the input of the field and not the variable. "This" also isn't being passed down or it could be an issue with node.js. Trying anything other than unchanged "code" gives compilation errors. I have attached the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import 'codemirror/keymap/sublime';
import 'codemirror/theme/monokai.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  reload = () => {
    this.setState({
      index: this.state.index+1,
      //index: this.state.index-1
    });
  }

  runCode = () => {
    this.setState({codea: true})
  }

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      DataisLoaded: false,
      count: 0,
      index: 0,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      age: '',
      email: '',
      description: '',
      hobbies: '',
      location: '',   
      codea: false,
      code: 'console.log("Hello World")',  
  };
  //this.Select = this.Select.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(
    //"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    "http://localhost")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
          this.setState({
              items: json,
              DataisLoaded: true
          });
      })
}

render() {

const videos = new Array("https://www.youtube.com/embed/aXXZwyeTJ98");
videos.push("https://www.youtube.com/embed/GnodscC2p-A");

var map = new Map();
for(var s = 0; s < videos.length; s++){
  map.set(videos[s]);
  } 

let i = 0;
while (i < videos.length) {
  if (i === this.state.count){
var video = videos[i];
}
  i++;
}
  
  const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
  if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
      <h1> Please wait some time.... </h1> </div> ;

var codea = 0;
var code = 'console.log("Hello World")';
return (
  <>   <div className = "App">
  <header className="App-header"> 
      <h1 className="text-1xl font-bold underline">    
        </h1>
        <table>
        <tr><td>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })}>
          [Last]
        </button>   </td><td><p><code>-</code> Video {this.state.count} <code>-</code> </p>
 </td><td>         <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          [Next]
        </button>
        
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        <iframe key={this.state.index} width="560" height="315" src={video} title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div ClassName ="absolute top-20 bottom-40 left-10 right-10 text-11">
</div>

<div>
        <CodeMirror
          value={this.state.code}
          options={{
            mode: 'python',
            lineNumbers: true,
          }}
          onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
             this.setState({
              codea: false,
              code: value,
            }
            
            )
          }}
        />
       
        <button onClick={() => axios.post("http://localhost:80/python", {code})}>[Run]</button>

        <div className="Output">
          <pre>{this.state.codea && this.state.code}</pre>
          
        </div>
      </div>    
      
      </header>
       </div>
       
 </> 
);
}
}
export default App;
```

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 80;
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const users = require("./users");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(users)
})

app.post('/python', (req, res) => {
if (req.body.code != null) {


fs.stat('test.py', function (err, stats) {
  console.log(stats);

  if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
      fs.writeFileSync("test.py", req.body.code);
  }

  fs.unlink('test.py',function(err){
       if(err) return console.log(err);
       console.log('file deleted successfully');
       fs.writeFileSync("test.py", req.body.code);
  });  
});

  var user = req.body.code;
    console.log({user});
 } else {
  console.log("Error1");
 }

if (req.body != null) {
  console.log("Success1");
 } else {
  console.log("Error1");
 }
 if (req.method === 'POST') {
   console.log("Post1");
}
else {
 console.log("?1");
}

})

app.post('/users', (req, res) => {  
  res.json({ message: "success" }); 
 
  if (req.body != null) {
    console.log("Success2");
   } else {
     console.log("Error2");
   }
   if (req.method === 'POST') {
     console.log("Post2");
 }
 else {
   console.log("?2");
 }

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})`
```

I have tried anything and everything I can think of. Nothing so far has worked.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Because you're definding `code` as the variable to send when you do `{ code }`, instead of `{ code: this.state.code }`</strike>

Try changing it to the code below:

```
<button
   onClick={() =>
      axios.post('http://localhost:80/python', {
         code: this.state.code,
      })
   }
>
   [Run]
</button>
```

#### Edit

I modified the `onChange` function to take only a single paramater.

Here's the updated component:

```
<CodeMirror
  value={this.state.code}
  options={{
    mode: "python",
    lineNumbers: true
  }}
  onChange={(value) => {
    this.setState({
      codea: false,
      code: value
    });
  }}
/>;
```

Check out the working example in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/76792725-mnl8zf)

Comment: I actually tried this exact same suggestion a few times before posting my code. I tried it  again copy pasting this code exact and it resulted in no code being sent to the server, unless it is left as the non-changed variable it won't give any results.  Remember this is a communication between node.js and react.js. What gets "this" passed down in react.js is either getting interfered with somehow (out of scope?) or there is something with the Node.js server I am missing. It either gives me a code error which stops up the compilation or it doesn't actually send anything to node.js.

Comment: Are there any other suggestion? This suggested code here and assumption that is has to do with "this" in that context doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\react\leetcode\client\src\App.js: Unexpected keyword 'this'. (41:73)

  39 |           }}
  40 |         />
> 41 |         <button onClick={() => axios.post("http://localhost:80/python", {this.state.code})}>[Run]</button>

Comment: Node.js is working now after taking out codemirror entirely and replacing it with text area and a function call to axios. I suppose I should update my code to reflect this. I'll just wait until my app is more developed to see if I can get codemirror to actually carry over the variable in some way. It just doesn't want to work this way I am using it.